# How to integrate MobX and react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, mobx

we have build an app in react native that uses react navigation and MobX.

Our app has a home page from which the user can go to an Article page. From that article page, the user can navigate to other Article page.

Right now, when navigating to an article page we store in Mobx store the id of the article we want to visit. When the article page opens, we get that value and display the appropriate article.

It works great except for when the user does HomePage -> Article A -> Article B -> go back

At this point, the article page still displays Article B because that is the value in the store.

What is the right way to handle this?